# Finding combinations of per-column row values such that columns have unique rows

Tags: r

The following is a seemingly simple puzzle that I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve.  Any help would be much appreciated.

I have a matrix with dimensions m=n of T/F values. Eg.

```
tf.m2 = matrix(c(F,T,T,F,T,T,F,F,F), ncol = 3)

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

The goal is to select for each column, a row value of TRUE such that no column uses the same row.
This is hard to convey so I included the desired solution for the above matrix below.

```
goal = rbind(c(2,3,1), c(3,2,1))

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3    NA
[2,]    3    2    NA
```

Here, each row is a different solution; each solution is an acceptable combination of row values in each column in the original matrix such that no combinations have used the same row twice.  Eg. `c(2,2,NA)` is not a solution.

I have really been smashing my head against the wall with this.  It seems simple, and probably is.  I'm just not getting it.

Here is also a non-toy example from my real data.

```
  tf.m2.l = matrix(c(F,T,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F,F,T,F,T,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F,F), ncol = 7)

      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[7,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE


  goal.l = rbind(c(2,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), c(2,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), c(5,7,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA), c(7,5,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]    2    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    2    7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    5    7   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    7    5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with.  I knew it was simple.  Sorry for the clutter, hopefully this helps someone some day.

```
  row.poss = alply(tf.m2.l, 2, function(x){
    if (!any(x)) { return(NA) }
    which(x)
  })
  poss.grid = expand.grid(row.poss)
  poss.grid.rep = adply(poss.grid, 1, function(x) {
    if(any(count(na.omit(unlist(x)))[,"freq"] > 1)) return(NULL)
    x
  })
poss.grid.rep

  1 2  3  4  5  6  7
1 2 5 NA NA NA NA NA
2 7 5 NA NA NA NA NA
3 2 7 NA NA NA NA NA
4 5 7 NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Turns out this method doesn't scale well as dim(M) and the number of TRUE values increase.  `grid.expand` generates an intermediate matrix with 100,000 rows with M=14 and sum(M)=36. The aaply step is then very slow.  I am looking for a modified grid.expand which does not duplicate row values, a fast way of removing duplicates, or an alternate solution.